# SupportsNoItemContext behaves differently on mac client and on web

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have noticed that SupportsNoItemContext behaves differently on Outlook for web and Outlook client for mac. In particular:

- Taskpane is not pinnable in the web version
- Taskpane disappears on message compose action in the web version

Below are the screens showing the difference in behavior

**Outlook for Mac**

[image: Outlook for Mac]

**Outlook for Web**

[image]

My manifest file is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>d744d71a-377c-4977-acc9-f3fb16cdc084</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Internet</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sample"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="For testing purposes only"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo_64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo_128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.13">
              <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <!-- Message Read mode-->
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                        <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                                        <!-- Enables your add-in to activate without the Reading Pane enabled or a message selected. -->
                                        <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
              <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo_16.png"/>
              <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo_32.png"/>
              <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo_80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
              <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
              <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test walkthrough"/>
              <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
              <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a task pane."/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Why taskpane disappears in message reply mode in both cases? how is it different from message compose?

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook on the Web, the expected behavior is that a SupportsNoItemContext task pane will close whenever the reading pane is hidden or a message isn't selected: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextless#feature-support-in-outlook-on-the-web-and-new-outlook-on-windows-preview. This happens because without the reading pane being open or a message selected, there's no add-in button accessible to the user in the UX. This is why the task pane is disappearing when you compose or reply to a message in Outlook on the Web.

The task pane should be pinnable in Outlook on the Web, however--I'm seeing the pin icon in my version but we'll keep trying to see if we can repro. I'll investigate the behavior on Mac as well (although that difference in reply/new compose does align with Windows, so is likely "as designed").

Comment: I've tested the following platforms:
1. Outlook for mac desktop app - Pin is there and taskpane is pinnable
2. Outlook for web on mac - no pin
3. Outlook for web on windows - no pin
4. Outlook for windows desktop app - no pin

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT